# Html.BuildImage param htmlAttributes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, image, html-helper

I have this plugin: ImageResizer.FluentExtensions.Mvc in my project.
This plugin contains one helper: Html.BuildImage and this helper contains multiples parameters, i have used the param: htmlAttributes  but dont work for me, my code:

`@Html.BuildImage("~/content/images/produto-foto/"+ (fotoPrincipal != null ? fotoPrincipal.FotoID : 0) + ".jpg", builder => builder.Resize(img => img.Dimensions(224,187)),Model.title, new {@class="img-produto"})`

This of response my html compiled:

`<img src="/content/images/produto-foto/8.jpg?width=224&amp;height=187" alt="">`

Does anyone have an idea what I'm doing wrong?

PS: Sorry for my english

Comment: Can you provide the implementation of `Html.BuildImage`?

Comment: Yes, this documentation: https://github.com/benfoster/ImageResizer.FluentExtensions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've linked to https://github.com/benfoster/ImageResizer.FluentExtensions as your source for `Html.BuildImage`'s implementation. I can find two implementations of such a method there.

```
public static MvcHtmlString BuildImage(this HtmlHelper html, string src, Action<ImageUrlBuilder> configure, string alternateText = "", object htmlAttributes = null)
{
  var imageUrl = html.CreateUrlHelper().ImageUrl(src, configure);
  return html.Image(imageUrl.ToString());
}

public static MvcHtmlString BuildImage(this HtmlHelper html, string src, ImageUrlBuilder builder, string alternateText = "", object htmlAttributes = null)
{
  var imageUrl = html.CreateUrlHelper().ImageUrl(src, builder);
  return html.Image(imageUrl.ToString());
}
```

Both of these completely ignore the `alternateText` and `htmlAttributes` arguments, so passing them along is useless.

In order to set the title and the class, you need to either build the image differently, or manually change the output of `BuildImage`.